# Java ADK Login application not working

Tags: java, android, authentication, passwords

So I'm super new to developing applications for Android, and have never touched Java before now. I'm trying to make an extremely simple app where you are shown a login screen, you enter a password (which is static and localized, I'm not at the point of using auth servers yet).

The `OnClick` callback compares the text currently in the `EditText` to the preset passcode (which is "1234") and decides whether to change to the activity that follows or to deny access.

When I run the app it works perfectly with no errors, except that when I tap the "Log In" button with 1234 in the `EditText`, I get no response. Nothing happens. Very frustrating. Please help and explain any corrections you make to my code, I'm eager to learn!

The class file for my activity.

[image: The class file for my activity]

Comment: To enable copy&paste for us, please post your code as formatted text inside your question, not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues that I can see in your code:

1. Why you are initializing your edittext twice, remove the second one in OnClickListener.
2. Calling setContentView is not enough to change the activity, you have to create another activity class and change the screen with the help of Intent. if you don'y know about Intent check this:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

3. To compare String there is a predefined method just use that like this:

   ```
   if(pinText.equalsIgnoreCase("1234")){
      // Call your intent here.
     }
   ```

   **I'll suggest to find a good tutorial series of Android Development on internet and start learning from there. I'll help you to understand the things in better way.**

Comment: This fixed my problem. I already watch multiple tutorial series and look forward to improving on my way to being a full blown developer. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome.I am sure you will.Just keep doing what you are doing.